# use uibinder css in java rather than xml

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

in my ui.xml, i have style like below

```
<ui:style src="../teststyle.css" />
```

if i want to programmatically use the style ***inside java file rather than ui.xml***,  in my widget how to call .setStyleName(..)  as the css is obfuscated

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to do the following steps to use the styles in your view class:

- Define a interface that extends `CssResource` in your view class

```
interface Style extends CssResource {

    String myStyle();

}
```

- Add a ui field of that type you just defined in your view class

```
@UiField
Style style;
```

- In your ui.xml add the `type` attribute to your `<ui:style>` element (the type must match the interface of step 1):

```
<ui:style type="com.example.MyView.Style">
```

- For each of the css classes you want to access in your view class you need to add a method to the `Style` interface (as done with `myStyle()`)
- You can now access the style via the `style` field (`style.myStyle()`)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually, the field has to be named 'style', not 'css'; or you should set an explicit field="" attribute on your <ui:style> to name the Java field, just like ui:field="" on elements and widgets.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't copy that part of my code.

Comment: <ui:style field='myStyle'> does not work with UiBinder. The GWT Eclipse highlighting does not see it as a problem, and it looks correct, but at runtime GWT throws "[ERROR] [...] - Template MyWindow.ui.xml has no ui:field attribute for ...MyWindow#supportStyles". Seems like a GWT bug.

Comment: Nice :)  ...  Much better than using a @external

Answer (score 2):

if i understand your question correct you have to define a class which extends from CssResource (you probably have done that already). In your view you can have a static instance of this class (let's call it `cssInstance`). In the constructor you have to call `cssInstance.ensureInjected()`. If you now want to add or set a style you can do it easly like  Example: `anyWidget.addStyleName(cssInstance.styleBorder());`

Comment: In addition: http://code.google.com/intl/en/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Programmatic_access